# drupal template page DEFINE problem

Tags: php, drupal

hi 
my drupal site is http://test.example.com

i have a template.php file in my theme folder

```
define('SITE_ROOT','http://example.com/abcd/');
```

i am using this SITE_ROOT for my custom functions

but echoing SITE_ROOT gives http://test.example.com

how is this happening.

plz help

Comment: What does `defined('SITE_ROOT')` return before you try to define it?

Answer (score 1):

Look for `define('SITE_ROOT'` in the whole drupal source code; it's probably defined somewhere in index.php or the config file.

Answer (score 0):

thank you guys

i find the solution . i defined the SITE_ROOT in settings.php file and everything worked fine.